# How do I properly compare two unsigned char's?

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking, char

Looking to compare two

```
BYTE PhysicalAddress[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
```

from the [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

where byte is defined in windows as `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`

Do I need to compare memory?

Thanks!

Comment: The objects are stored in memory. Whichever way you compare, you will be comparing memory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matteo beat me to it.  His answer is correct.  Unfortunately I could not comment directly on his post (I may be too new here), but I wanted to confirm his response since the majority of answers thus far are incorrect.

The data type in question is an array of bytes.

Do NOT use the equality operator (==) for comparing the values of two arrays, it will only evaluate to true if you're comparing the *same array to itself*.  Even if the byte arrays have the same values across each of their elements, yet are different arrays (and therefore reside at different places in memory), the equality operator will return false.

In essence, an array is just a pointer in memory.  Here are two ways to declare arrays:

```
    int * pointer = new int[5];
```

or:

```
    int array[] = new int[5];
```

You can access the first element with either:

```
    *pointer = 100;  // Dereference the pointer to get the int at that location
```

or:

```
    array[0] = 100;
```

You can even do:

```
    *array = 100;
```

or:

```
    pointer[0] = 100;
```

This should demonstrate that an 'array' is just a pointer to the first element of a block of contiguous memory.  So, when comparing two arrays to eachother using the equality operator, it's the same as comparing two pointers to eachother.  To re-iterate the main point, if the arrays are not in the same space in memory, the pointers point to different places, and are therefore not 'equal,' at least in terms of the equality operator.

I hope this is appropriate information for your skill level :)  If not, perhaps it will help someone else.  Also, it's been a while since I've had the pleasure of using C++, so hopefully everything is correct.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. So is it comparing the addresses in this case?

Comment: If you were to compare two arrays using the equality operator (==), you would merely be comparing their addresses, yes.  Arrays are just convenient syntax around pointers, the values of pointers point to addresses in memory, and using "==" compares values. :)

Comment: Arrays **are not pointers**. They are a completely separate type with very different semantics. However, the *name* of an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element in most contexts in C.

Comment: @R- thanks for putting it so eloquently. Far too many programmers cannot answer the question 'Whats the difference between char x[] "abc" and char *x = "abc"?'

Answer (score 6):

Be careful: the definition of `PhysicalAddress`, as explained in the documentation, is

```
  BYTE PhysicalAddress[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
```

i.e. it's an *array* of `BYTE`s. Still, you can compare them easily with `memcmp` from `<string.h>` (or `<cstring>` if you're using C++):

```
// The two structures
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES iaa1, iaa2;
// The result of the comparison
int result;

//...

if(iaa1.PhysicalAddressLength!=iaa2.PhysicalAddressLength)
{
    // We have two physical addresses of two different lengths; depending on what
    // you want to do it may be an error or just a simpler case of comparison
}
else
{
    // Perform the comparison
    result = memcmp(iaa1.PhysicalAddress, iaa2.PhysicalAddress, iaa1.PhysicalAddressLength);
}
```

Comment: Soudns good however, I am not catching on to the size check comment "it may be an error or just a simpler case of comparison"....could you expand on this please..thank you

Comment: Depending on the aim of your code a comparison of addresses of different length may not make sense (because you are comparing different kind of addresses), or may be an optimization (if one is shorter you don't have to compare their content, you already know they are different).

Answer (score 4):

Compare? Just use ordinary equality and/or relational comparison operators. Is there something wrong with this approach? Why do you suddenly want to compare memory?

Comment: @Tommy: The question explicitly states that you want to compare two unsigned chars. Then it turns out that you want to compare two arrays. Why did you ask about comparing two unsigned chars when you actually want to compare two arrays?